# UIScrollView like the new iOS App Store

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, app-store, image-gallery

I need to do something like the new app store as shown on the attached image
[image: App Store ScreenShot]

however, i know that i have to use scroll view with some images or button inside

but im wondering about the curves and sliding images, resizing while scrolling, im talking about the all features of that

any good example or explanation ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some codes emulating the look and feel of the Appstore apps:

The WellSegmentedController:
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sdwellsegmentedcontrol

The image Carussel:
http://www.binpress.com/app/icarousel/614

I know someone also made the paginated grid code, but I simply can't find it anymore. However, a good look at cocoacontrols.com should give you all the spare parts you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use UIKit, take a look at UICollectionView. There's a good starting tutorial here by Ray Wenderlich - http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Warning, it's iOS6+ only though for that class set.